# Mathematical Analysis help

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, convergence-divergence

Let $f$ be differentiable on $(0,\infty)$ and suppose $\lim_{x\rightarrow\ \infty}(f(x)+f'(x))=L$. Then, $\lim_{x\rightarrow\ \infty}f(x)= L$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow\ \infty}f'(x)= 0$

My approach: $\lim_{x\rightarrow\ \infty}f(x)= \lim_{x\rightarrow\ \infty}\frac{f(x)e^x}{e^x} =\lim_{x\rightarrow\ \infty}\frac{f(x)e^x+f'(x)e^x}{e^x }=L$. But this is only valid if we can show $\lim_{x\rightarrow\ \infty}f(x)e^x=\infty$. Could anyone advise please?

Comment: hint: see what happens if lim f'(x) =/=0 as x-->+oo

Comment: L'Hôpital's rule  applies when the denominator has infinite limit; it does not matter what the numerator does. See the note at the end of  the "general proof" [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#General_proof).

Comment: @DavidMitra, Does that also hold if the numerator $n(x)$ diverges to several partial limits, where $\limsup_{x\to\infty}n(x)=\infty$?

Comment: @JonathanY. Yes. A precise statement of the rule for this case is "Let $f$ and $g$ be differentiable on $(0,\infty)$ and $g'(x)\ne0 $ for all $x\in(0,\infty)$. Suppose that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty} g(x)=\pm\infty$. If $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}{f'(x)\over g'(x)}=L $, then $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}{f'(x)\over g'(x)}=L$". This includes the case when $L$ is infinite. c.f. *Introduction to Real Analysis*, Bartle and Sherbert, pg. 180.

Comment: @David A better and even more careful discussion of this critical yet often mangled calculational tool can be found in Kenneth Ross' ELEMENTARY ANALYSIS: THE THEORY OF CALCULUS.Just in case anyone needs to brush up or has never seen a really careful treatment before.

Answer (score 1):

Define the function $g$ on $(0,\infty)$ by $g(x)=f(x)\,\mathrm e^x$, then $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}g'(x)\,\mathrm e^{-x}=L$. Let $K\lt L\lt M$, then there exists $z$ depending on $(K,M)$ such that $K\,\mathrm e^x\lt g'(x)\lt M\,\mathrm e^x$ for every $x\geqslant z$. Integrating this double inequality on $(z,x)$ yields 
$$
K\,\mathrm e^x-K\,\mathrm e^z+g(z)\lt g(x)\lt M\,\mathrm e^x-M\,\mathrm e^z+g(z)
$$ 
for every $x\geqslant z$, that is, $K-K_z\,\mathrm e^{-x}\lt f(x)\lt M-M_z\,\mathrm e^{-x}$ for some finite $K_z$ and $M_z$. In particular, $K\leqslant\liminf\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)\leqslant\limsup\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)\leqslant M$. This holds for every $K\lt L\lt M$ hence 
$$
\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L.
$$
Finally, $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)+f'(x)=L$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$ hence 
$$
\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0.
$$

Comment: Hmm... the spacing $\mathrm e$ gives is slightly odd.

Comment: Hence killing a standard students' myth. Calculus is only "easy"if your course involves problems you don't have to do any THINKING to solve-which is sadly all too common nowadays. If students had more problems like this on thier homeworks and exams,they wouldn't have that ignorant opinion.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 What are you referring to now?